# Reading a date in a pandas dataFrame column as base day to generate hourly data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column of data in a pandas dataFrame like:

Date:

```
1960-01-01 
1960-01-02
1960-01-03
```

I need to read the first value as base day like (Date[0] which is 1960-01-01) to use in the function below:

```
Base = Date[0]

arr = numpy.array( [base + datetime.timedelta(hours=i) for i in range(len(daily)] )
```

error:

```
ufunc add cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('O')
```

Comment: "I keep getting errors."  What errors?!

Comment: I have added the error:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this Python object:

```
datetime.timedelta(hours=i)
```

With the NumPy equivalent:

```
np.timedelta64(i, 'h')
```